# Scrolling dropdown menu scrolling too much

Tags: javascript, css, menu, scroll, drop-down-menu

I am using the following solution to scroll very long menus in my dropdowns:

http://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/

Is there any way to stop the menu's from scrolling and becoming any shorter once the last menu item has appeared? At the moment, they keep shrinking even when the menu has fully loaded. I would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think your trying to say your actual menu list items are shrinking?  I'm not exactly sure if your saying the whole menu itself shrinks or just the items itself.

Try giving the (Li)'s a height and see if that keeps them consistent.  Example.

```
nav li:hover li {height:3em;}
```

or

```
nav li:hover ul a {height:3em;}
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: No, I'm saying the hole menu keeps shrinking/scrolling even when the last menu item has appeared. I would like it to stop scrolling once it has reached the end, setting the height on the li's or a's did not fix that.